# Why are type annotations different on functions and variables?

Tags: typescript

I think the following code is assigning type `string` to type `unknown`, but compiler give an opposite error message.

```js
let y: (arg: unknown) => any;
let y1: unknown

y = (s: string) => s // Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
y1 = "y1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because functions can be called from other places.

Take this, for example:

```
let y: (arg: unknown) => any = (arg) => arg
y(123) // fine
```

This is a perfectly acceptable invocation of `y()`. `unknown` can be anything, so passing a number there is fine.

Now do this:

```
let y: (arg: unknown) => any = (arg) => arg
y = (s: string) => s.toUpperCase()
y(123) // crash
```

`number` would no longer be a valid argument for `y()` because `(s: string) => any` would let the function assume that the argument was a `string`, but no guarantee can be made here.

This means that the argument type in the function type `unknown` must be assignable to the argument type in what you are assigning `string` (because you can still call the function with an `unknown` argument). And `unknown` is not assignable to `string`.

Answer (score 2):

[Variance](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance)!

The definition of `y` *accepts* any argument, including let's say `1`. But the implementation only works on `string`, so `y(1)` will be an error.

`y1` is different: it *can be* any value, including `1`, `y1` and `(s: string) => s`, and it's up to whoever is using it to consume strings, integers and functions.

See also [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19739576/288201).